# Match exact string and random string length in between

Tags: regex

I hate regex and I really can't get my head around it properly. I'm trying to match the following example:

`fwb fcb"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/random.length?`

while **random.length** can be any word with upper/lowercase letters, a dot or a number. And it ends with the `?` so the question mark indicates the end.

I came as far as:

`/fwb fcb"><a href="https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/` **missing bit** `?/g`

Any help?

Comment: Replace: `random.length?` with `[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\?` should do the trick.

`a-z` matches all lowercase letters.
`A-Z` matches all uppercase letters.
`0-9` matches all digits.

You need to escape the dot with a backslash as it has a special meaning in regex.

`+` means that the length of the string can be anything from 1 to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

the missing part could be `(\w|\.)+` if underscore was accepted. Otherwise, like in your case, you have to specify all different possibilities: `[A-Za-z0-9\.]+`. Pay attention because in your regex there are some characters that need to be escaped (. and ? are an example).